# How to check the process of an action while pressing down a key debugging? (Java, Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

This may have a very simple answer but I'm a begginer at coding and can't find the answer to this anywhere. I'm having trouble with an attack animation in a combat game I'm programming and I would like to find the source of the problem debugging. The situation is that I don't know how to press a key (the attack key, so the attack animation starts running) in the game while being in debug mode, because otherwise, the debug continues as if the character isn't receiving any commands. What do I need to do, or where should I place breakpoints to be able to do this? The IDE I'm using is Eclipse and the language is java.

Comment: if this is a console input then open the console tab and press ya keys

Comment: You might consider using a logging framework to log the state of your program as it runs.

Comment: It's a game that opens up in a window frame.

Comment: What GUI library? Swing? JavaFx? What code? What problems are you having when using breakpoints? You've surely experimented with this before coming here, right?